# Ubuntu does not boot

Tags: boot, grub2

here is the link to my disk repair boot report:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23204719/

Ubuntu installer is not managing to configure Grub properly. Basically I install ubuntu with a usb stick, all the installation goes fine but after rebooting the computer does not find Ubuntu and says "`no bootable device`". Installed on Acer Aspire ES11 with EFI bios version 1.22.

The drive where ubuntu is installed is

```
/dev/mmcblk0p2

/dev/mmcblk0p1 is fat32 512mb

/dev/mmcblk0p2 is ext4 26.71gb

/dev/mmcblk0p3 is linux swap
```

1 is flagged as boot in `GPARTED`

"EMMC: HBG4e 32G" is selected as boot in the bios. The bios of the acer aspire does not even allow to select/deselect anything; just order things. right now I have : 1)usbHDD 2)USBFDD 3)EMMC: HBG4e 32G 4)network boot IPV4 5)USB CDROM 6)Network boot IPV6. All I can do is change the order

I have done boot repair multiple times and it never works

here is the report after boot repair but it still does not work: http://paste.ubuntu.com/23207078

Thank you

Comment: "Ubuntu installer is not managing to configure Grub properly" Why? What is the error that you receive when it tries to?

Comment: I updated the post :)

Comment: Did you set the right partition to boot in the UEFI settings of your BIOS?

Comment: yes, the bios of the acer spire does not even allow you to select/deselect anything; just order things. The internal mmc is first and usb second

Comment: You have to select the efi folder in order for uefi to work, not the disk.. Or you move everything to mbr, and there you select the disk

Comment: You have to select the efi folder in order for uefi to work, not the disk.. Or you move everything to mbr, and there you select the disk

Comment: there is nothing I can select. Everything available is in the lista already and there is nothing else available in the bios. right now I have : 1)usbHDD 2)USBFDD 3)EMMC: HBG4e 32G 4)network boot IPV4 5)USB CDROM 6)Network boot IPV6. All I can do is change the order

Comment: What model Acer Aspire do you have and what is the BIOS version?

Comment: acer aspire es11 bios v1.22

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered allowing Boot Repair to accomplish the suggested repair rather than attempting to choose the correct options yourself?

Note: Your pastebin shows a number of mis-configured items and indicates "The settings chosen by the user will not act on the boot."

Comment: I have done boot repair multiple times and it never works. All I have done is install ubuntu like I did in the past... Nothing fancy but never had this issue before

Answer (score 0):

This is bug 1173457, installer does not set up the EFI properly on remote media (USB in the bug, but you could add your sd info).  You can copy everything from the hard disk's EFI partition to the SD's EFI partition to see if that works, or you could try to boot off the hard disk and select ubuntu (shim/grub).  Try the EFI menu (some function key at power-up to select disk/os to boot).  And do add yourself to the bug, it's three years old, and few are on the list, even though everyone who has tried to install to a UEFI usb has been affected.

Note, the grub-install has been updated somewhat to allow a manual installation to the remote-media, but the "secure" switch does not properly use shim instead of grub.

---

Boot-repair does not know about mmcblk devices, but if you put the SD card into an USB reader, maybe it can fix it.